# MVCSiteMapProvider overriding GetDynamicNodeCollection with multiple requests

Tags: mvcsitemapprovider

I am using MVCSiteMapProvider for MVC5. I have created my own implementation of DynamicNodeProviderBase to dynamically create nodes in my site map based on a collection of categories for our product catalogue.

I am using SimpleInjector and have a MvcSiteMapProviderContainerInitializer that I pull from the sample project for the site map provider. This is working fine.

However, when calling Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath() this results a call to GetDynamicNodeCollection for every request. Can the dynamic node collection be done once per lifetime of the container rather then on a per request basis?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The class I have implemented is actually created as a singleton, so for now I have initialised the nodes collection from within the constructor. This will do now.

However, I saw this blog post from 2012 but the interface seems to have changed in later versions of the provider so this is no longer possible

http://xharze.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/inside-mvcsitemapprovider-part-2.html?m=1

Comment: Singleton is not supported. The nodes that the dynamic node provider are loaded at startup and cached, so there is no need to do it anyway.